# Protecting node/express endpoints from attacks via delay with backoff

Tags: node.js, express

I want to protect some endpoints from hacking attempts and also DoS/DDoS attacks, e.g. login, password reset, register.

I want to implement a delay (i.e. `setTimeout`) with linear or exponential backoff (not throttling):

- request 1: no delay
- request 2: 1000ms
- request 3: 1000ms + x
- request 4: 1000ms + x + y
- ...

I've done this before but not in node.

I realise the attacker can't starve my thread pool by launching 1000s of concurrent requests because there is no thread pool in node.

However, each request results in some small amount of memory to be allocated. So the attacker could launch 1000s of concurrent requests and exhaust my server's memory.

Is my understanding correct? Is there an elegant way to handle this, or is it unavoidable (and so I should accept it, or consider an alternative like throttling)?

Comment: Delaying the request response would only keep connections (and memory) for longer than they should. Not sure if useful for DDOS mitigation. The attackers don't wait for the answer before sending another hundred requests.

Comment: @Seblor Delay and throttling are common techniques for this, but you are right, that's a good point. I suppose it wouldn't solve all problems, but it's a piece of a larger security strategy. I suppose one would starve memory and the other would starve space (assuming writes to a db/store). So no easy solution :(

Comment: Throttling the bandwidth for the incriminated hosts is good, it saves bandwidth for the normal clients. Delaying is completly ignored by the attackers, AFAIK.

Comment: @Seblor What do you mean by "throttling the bandwidth", do you mean dropping/ignoring requests for throttled IPs?

Comment: Throttling the bandwidth would be limiting the bandwidth available for certain IPs. The goal for this is to keep available "free" bandwidth for legit connections.

Comment: @Seblor Oh. So that would be done at an infrastructural level, right? Could I do such a thing in node?

Comment: Ideally, The Delay and Throttling should be implemented by another app -- not with the actual app. There should be a separate app which would take care of Delay and then reverse proxy (forward) the request to your app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding DDoS security at the application level is a bad practice. This should be implemented by previous layers, eg. WAF / Cloudflare.

Throttling is good for when you serve larger batches of data. For HTML content it will be difficult to consider them as real security. It is better to limit the number of simultaneous connections eg in nginx.

Only at the end you can implement restrictions in the application. **And it should not be delays**. Your goal is to handle the request as soon as possible. So introducing some form of rate-limiting (**HTTP 429 Too Many Requests**)

Answer (score 2):

It is better to protect against DDoS on web server proxy/balancer level.

Protection against brute-force can be done with [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible), here is [login protection example](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#login-endpoint-protection) and [an article with more examples](https://medium.com/@animirr/brute-force-protection-node-js-examples-cd58e8bd9b8d)